# How to convert System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection to CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, connection-string

How to convert System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection to CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo

Is it Possible?Somebody help on this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

according to [MSDN for ConnectionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226300%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the ConnectionInfo object is just what it states, info about the connection.  [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) is used for making a connection to a database.

SqlConnection has the necessary info to create a ConnectionInfo object.
specifically, 
[DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.datasource.aspx),
[Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.database.aspx), and
[Credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.credential.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you create a new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo object and set it's properties equal to the corresponding property on the SqlConnection?

Answer (score 0):

Found myself in a similar situation and the solution is not to convert the sqlconnection itself to a connectioninfo but to use the connection string. Following code using SqlConnectionStringBuilder is doing just that :

```
ConnectionInfo connection = new ConnectionInfo();

string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_2Focus.Properties.Settings._2ServeConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
connection.ServerName = builder.DataSource;
connection.DatabaseName = builder.InitialCatalog;
connection.IntegratedSecurity = builder.IntegratedSecurity;
if (!builder.IntegratedSecurity)
{
    connection.Password = builder.Password;
    connection.UserID = builder.UserID;
}

Tables CrTables = report.Database.Tables 
foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
{
    CrTable.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connection;
    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(CrTable.LogOnInfo);
}
```

This question is way old, the op does not have many points, so probably this won't get marked as answer. Anyway I think it is the right thing to do.